# cmake ExternalProject_Add project not building before targets that depend on it

Tags: cmake, ninja

I have

```
ExternalProjectAdd(googletest ......)
...
add_library(gtest_main UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(gtest_main PROPERTIES
    "IMPORTED_LOCATION" ${binary_dir}/googlemock/gtest/libgtest_main.a
)
...
add_executable(sometest somefile.cpp)
target_link_library(sometest gtest_main)
add_dependencies(sometest googletest)
```

But evidently stating the dependency of the executable `sometest` on `googletest` does not actually require the `ExternalProject_Add`'s build command to be invoked prior to the build command for `sometest`.

If I run `ninja` then it complains that it can't find `libgtest_main.a`. But if you call `ninja googletest && ninja sometest` it works just fine.

So, how do you tell `cmake` that `sometest` depends on `googletest`'s build command being invoked?

Comment: Call `add_dependencies(sometest googletest)` which you currently use should do the trick. Show more details about `ExternalProject_Add` call. (E.g. check that build directory for external project isn't `googletest/...`: not sure about ninja, but makefile definitely doesn't like a directory and a target with the same name.)

Comment: personally I prefer  `add_dependencies(gtest_main googletest_project)` and since you executable depend on `gtest_main` ....

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It seems to me like the problem only occurs with ninja. Simply switching to make runs the build command for the ExternalProject before attempting to link. I don't know if that's a ninja problem then or a cmake problem.

Comment: Hit the same with ninja, solved with make or building the dependency first.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is related to **Ninja** generator and its mechanism of scanning dependencies ([more details](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/760)).

For solve the issue need to add additional **Cmake** option **BUILD_BYPRODUCTS** with expected path to library that will be compiled:

```
ExternalProject_add(
    ...
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googlemock/gtest/libgtest_main.a
)
```

This should help to get rid of error like this:

> ninja: error: 'gtest/libgtest_main.a', needed by 'sometest.so',
> missing and no known rule to make it

I understand that answer is quite late, but hope that it will help someone safe few hours.